# How to convert 24 hrs time to 12 hours format in java using the date from the database

Tags: java

I just want to convert a date from the database to 12 hours format which is originally in 24 hours format which is something like this `2015-06-11T28:28:57.000Z`. In here this time format (`28:25:57`) seems to be the next day (ie. `2015-06-12T04:28:57`).

I have tried with the following:

```
String date = "2015-06-11T28:28:57.000Z";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss a");
Date date = formatter.parse(date);
```

but I got an error like unparsable date.

Comment: is the date stored as a string in the database? why not store it as a date/time type?

Comment: Where exactly is the exception thrown? Do you have a stack strace?

Comment: If you have date like that `2015-06-11T28:28:57.000Z` in the db, then it is an error

Comment: Just a guess, but I think 28 is not a valid value for _hours_. Maybe you have written the minutes also to the hours placeholder when wrinting the date to the db.

Answer (score 0):

Your date formatter string was incorrect, Try this:

```
    String dateStr = "2015-06-11T28:28:57.000Z";
    SimpleDateFormat sdfInput = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    Date date = sdfInput.parse(dateStr);
    System.out.println("Date:"+date ); //Fri Jun 12 04:28:57 IST 2015

    // to get 12 hour date formate date-string from provided date
    SimpleDateFormat sdfOutput = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS ");
    String dateStr2 = sdfOutput.format(date);
    System.out.println("dateStr2:" + dateStr2); //2015-06-12 04:28:57.000
```